# How long were Jedi Councillors' term lengths?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

There are five lifetime Jedi Councillors (Yoda, Mace Windu, Ki-Adi-Mundi, Oppo Rancisis and Plo Koon in Eps. I-III) that served until they either step down or death do them part.

There are four long-term Jedi Councillors, who could step down at any time but their terms of service were time-limited.

And finally, three short-term Jedi Councillors (Anakin was a short-term Jedi Councillor before turning to the dark side) who are usually brought in to deal with a crisis or to bring the voices of otherwise-underrepresented branches of the Order.

So how long are the terms of service of the time-limited Councillors?

Also, which Councillors from the movies were long-term Councillors? Which ones, other than Anakin, were short-term Councillors?

Comment: It seems to me from the way you form the question that you allready know the answer. I do not understand the term councilor tho. Do you mean Jedi Master?

Comment: He means Jedi Masters that are on the High Council (on Coruscant)

Comment: Where are you getting this information about short and long term council members?

Comment: The "Power of the Jedi" sourcebook was the only source I know about that specifically mentioned the existence of short and long-term Councillors.

Comment: I don't see this information anywhere in the "Power of the Jedi" sourcebook - http://cporter.net/rpgs/books/Star%20Wars/Power%20Of%20The%20Jedi%20Sourcebook.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the below is Legends only. We just don't have enough information in Canon.

Unfortunately, we don't have a lot of information from Legends, either. [Wookieepedia has a list of known members](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_High_Council#Known_members), with dates, but most members have either a start date or an end date; very few have both, and most of those that do were killed in action while serving.

But let's look at them anyway:

- **[Atris](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Atris), [Kavar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kavar), [Zez-Kai Ell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zez-Kai_Ell), [Vrook Lamar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vrook_Lamar), and [Lonna Vash](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lonna_Vash)** all served for 12 years, before being killed during the events of the [*Knights of the Old Republic II*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords) video game. In the story of that game, the Jedi are in hiding following a [massive attack on the Order](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Jedi_Purge). Considering the circumstances, they only served in any meaningful way for at least 11 years.
- **[Vandar Tokare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vandar_Tokare)** served for 11 years before being killed on [Katarr](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Devastation_of_Katarr)
- **[Syo Bakarn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Syo_Bakarn)** served for at least 10 years, before extenuating circumstances lead to his removal<sup>1</sup>
- **[Jaric Kaedan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jaric_Kaedan)** served for just about two or three years, before being killed in action
- **[Omo Bouri](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Omo_Bouri)** served for 12 years. He actually survived to the end of his tenure, so his term was at least that long.
- **[Jocasta Nu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jocasta_Nu)** served for 10 years.
- **[T'un](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T%27un)** served for at least 50 years. We don't know whether he stepped down or was killed.
- **[Mace Windu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mace_Windu) and [Plo Koon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Plo_Koon)** may not be the best examples, since they're lifetime members, but they served for 25 years before dying
- **[Ki-Adi Mundi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi)** served for 14 years before his death
- **[Coleman Trebor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coleman_Trebor)** served for 5 years before his death
- **[Shaak Ti](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shaak_Ti)** served for 7 years before her death
- **[Kit Fisto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kit_Fisto) and [Obi-Wan Kenobi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi)** both served for three years before the collapse of the Jedi Order; Fisto died, but obviously Kenobi didn't
- **[Agen Kolar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Agen_Kolar), [Coleman Kcaj](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coleman_Kcaj), and [Stass Allie](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stass_Allie)** each served for only one year before their deaths.

Based on this, we can assume that non-permanent councillors serve terms of *at least* ten years, but that's the most specific we can be.

---

<sup>1</sup> Spoilers for the Jedi Consular storyline of *Star Wars: The Old Republic*:

> Bakarn had been compromised by the Sith Emperor. His ultimate fate is player determined (it's possible to kill him, but also possible to save him), and I'm not sure if one is more canon than the other. Either way, he's no longer on the council.

Comment: Jocasta Nu stepped down after 10 years of service, but it is not known whether she was permanent or not at the time. The residual question is then whether 12 years could be long-term or short-term as far as the Jedi Order is concerned.

Comment: @NSERCProtester Agreed; personally I suspect she was a temporary councillor, since she was also the Jedi Librarian at the time, but we don't know. However, she has the shortest term of people who survived to step down, so she's the lower bound regardless of whether she was a permanent member or not. To suggest that the terms were shorter (or had a longer minimum length) is pure speculation

Comment: I think alternate endings are lower S-canon (in pre-Disney rules) while default ending is C-canon. Which outcome was default in the game?

Comment: @DVK I haven't played the game, so I'm not certain. The writeup on Wookieepedia suggests that both possibilities are Light-sided, which makes things harder. It's pretty moot, in my opinion; regardless of the outcome, the PC replaces Bakarn on the Council

Comment: @DVK I don't think there is a default.  I think it is merely a choice that will award you light or dark side points as appropriately.